# A closed-form solution of $\textbf{R}\textbf{R}_1=\textbf{R}_2\textbf{R}$ w.r.t $\textbf{R}$

Tags: rotation

Is there a closed-form solution of $\textbf{R}\textbf{R}_1=\textbf{R}_2\textbf{R}$ with respect to $\textbf{R}\in SO(3)$?

$\textbf{R}_1$, $\textbf{R}_2 \in SO(3)$ are given.

Added:

I tried holmeski's solution but it fails because of rank deficiency in A matrix.(why?) The following code simulates holmeski's solution in matlab. (please correct me if the code is incorrect)

```
clear all
cTl=rotx(rand*100)*roty(rand*100)*rotz(rand*100)
lTc = inv(cTl)

for k = 1: 9
    l1Tl2{k}=rotx(rand*100)*roty(rand*100)*rotz(rand*100)
    c1Tc2{k}= cTl*l1Tl2{k}*lTc;
end
R = calib_RR1_R2R_closedform(l1Tl2,c1Tc2)  


function R = calib_RR1_R2R_closedform(l1Tl2,c1Tc2_klt)    

Astack=[]
for k = 1:length(l1Tl2)
    R1 = l1Tl2{k}(1:3,1:3);
    R2 = c1Tc2_klt{k}(1:3,1:3);
    A = [ R1(1,1) + R1(1,2) + R1(1,3) - R2(1,1) - R2(1,2) - R2(1,3), R1(2,1) + R1(2,2) + R1(2,3) - R2(2,1) - R2(2,2) - R2(2,3), R1(3,1) + R1(3,2) + R1(3,3) - R2(3,1) - R2(3,2) - R2(3,3), R1(1,1) + R1(1,2) + R1(1,3) - R2(1,1) - R2(1,2) - R2(1,3), R1(2,1) + R1(2,2) + R1(2,3) - R2(2,1) - R2(2,2) - R2(2,3), R1(3,1) + R1(3,2) + R1(3,3) - R2(3,1) - R2(3,2) - R2(3,3), R1(1,1) + R1(1,2) + R1(1,3) - R2(1,1) - R2(1,2) - R2(1,3), R1(2,1) + R1(2,2) + R1(2,3) - R2(2,1) - R2(2,2) - R2(2,3), R1(3,1) + R1(3,2) + R1(3,3) - R2(3,1) - R2(3,2) - R2(3,3)]
    Astack = [Astack; A];
end

det(Astack)

[U S V] = svd(Astack);
x=V(:,end);
R=reshape(x,3,3);
```

Comment: A faster way of constructing A would to use the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation#Existence_and_uniqueness_of_the_solutions), namely `A = kron(I, R2) - kron(R1', I);` and after this you can also get the solutions by looking at the null space of A: `null(A)`. But from my testing it seems that you will always get three solutions, so any linear combination of those is still a valid solution. So you would still need to find which linear combination yields a rotation matrix.

Comment: I also did some numerical testing and it seems that there is never an unique solution, there is always a circular line of solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That will be very useful for my later research! You are right about the non-unique solution. According to the paper in the link below in my answer, one pair of the equation is not enough to determine the unique solution. I will edit my answer soon.

Comment: Then at least this method does limit the search space from 9 dimensions to only 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can solve this using a least squares approach since all the math in equation is linear. Rearrange the equation so
\begin{equation}
\bf RR_1 -R_2R = 0
\end{equation}

Set up the relation 
\begin{equation}
\bf Ax = b
\end{equation}

where the vector $\bf x$ contains all values of $\bf R$, $\bf B$ is a $[9,1]$ zero vector, and $\bf A$ is a $[9,9]$ matrix which contains the $\bf R_1$ and $R_2$ terms.

Then solve for $\bf x$
\begin{equation}
\bf x = A^{-1} b
\end{equation}

You'll then have to restructure the $\bf x$ vector back into $\bf R$.

I know this may not be exactly what you're looking for but it is a closed form solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Auctaully, I already have a non-linear model for the optimization as $e = log(e^{[r]_x}\textbf{R}\textbf{R}_1)-log(\textbf{R}_2e^{[r]_x}\textbf{R})$ where $\textbf{r}\in so(3)$. It works well but just wondering if there is a closed form solution:) Thanks anyway!

Comment: Is the nonlinear approach an iterative solver? Is what I proposed not closed form?

Comment: You are right! I just realized that your answer is what I was looking for. Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: But this would always give $R=0$, since $b$ is a vector of zeros. But clearly $0\notin SO(3)$.

Comment: You could check if the $A$ matrix has an eigenvalue of zero, in which case its corresponding eigenvector would be a solution.

Comment: Note also that the reconstructed $R$ might (and is very likely) not be an element of $SO(3)$.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be made easier when formulating an equivalent problem using [unit quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation)

$$
q\,q_a = q_b\,q \tag{1}
$$

where each quaternions can be expressed as $w + x\,i + y\,j + z\,k$ while satisfying that $w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$, where $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = i\,j\,k = -1$ (it can be noted that $i$, $j$ and $k$ do not [commute](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Commute.html), for example $i\,j \neq j\,i$).

For quaternions multiplication it can be shown that it can be written as a matrix vector product, where the matrix is a function of one of the two quaternions. Namely when considering the quaternions $q = q_1 + q_2\,i + q_3\,j + q_4\,k$ and $r = r_1 + r_2\,i + r_3\,j + r_4\,k$, then their product can be written as

$$
\begin{align}
q\,r &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & i & j & k
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
q_1 & -q_2 & -q_3 & -q_4 \\
q_2 &  q_1 & -q_4 &  q_3 \\
q_3 &  q_4 &  q_1 & -q_2 \\
q_4 & -q_3 &  q_2 &  q_1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
r_1 \\ r_2 \\ r_3 \\ r_4
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & i & j & k
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
r_1 & -r_2 & -r_3 & -r_4 \\
r_2 &  r_1 &  r_4 & -r_3 \\
r_3 & -r_4 &  r_1 &  r_2 \\
r_4 &  r_3 & -r_2 &  r_1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
q_1 \\ q_2 \\ q_3 \\ q_4
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

Dividing by a unit quaternions is the same as multiplication with its conjugate, which is defined as negating the complex parts: $w - x\,i - y\,j - z\,k$. This allows us to write equation $(1)$ as

$$
q\,q_a\,q^{-1} = q_b
$$

which is equivalent to

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
q_1 & -q_2 & -q_3 & -q_4 \\
q_2 &  q_1 & -q_4 &  q_3 \\
q_3 &  q_4 &  q_1 & -q_2 \\
q_4 & -q_3 &  q_2 &  q_1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 q_1 &  q_2 &  q_3 &  q_4 \\
-q_2 &  q_1 & -q_4 &  q_3 \\
-q_3 &  q_4 &  q_1 & -q_2 \\
-q_4 & -q_3 &  q_2 &  q_1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
q_{a,1} \\ q_{a,2} \\ q_{a,3} \\ q_{a,4}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
q_{b,1} \\ q_{b,2} \\ q_{b,3} \\ q_{b,4}
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{2}
$$

It can be shown that, while using the fact that $q$ is a unit quaternion, the two matrices in the above equation can be combined into the following expression

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
q_1 & -q_2 & -q_3 & -q_4 \\
q_2 &  q_1 & -q_4 &  q_3 \\
q_3 &  q_4 &  q_1 & -q_2 \\
q_4 & -q_3 &  q_2 &  q_1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 q_1 &  q_2 &  q_3 &  q_4 \\
-q_2 &  q_1 & -q_4 &  q_3 \\
-q_3 &  q_4 &  q_1 & -q_2 \\
-q_4 & -q_3 &  q_2 &  q_1
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1-2(q_3^2+q_4^2) & 2(q_2q_3-q_1q_4) & 2(q_2q_4+q_1q_3) \\
0 & 2(q_2q_3+q_1q_4) &  1-2(q_2^2+q_4^2) & 2(q_3q_4-q_1q_2) \\
0 & 2(q_2q_4-q_1q_3) & 2(q_3q_4+q_1q_2) & 1-2(q_2^2+q_3^2)
\end{bmatrix} \tag{3}
$$

the lower right $3\times3$ matrix of the the right hand side of $(3)$ is just the rotation matrix representation of $q$, denoted as $R(q)$. Substituting this result back into equation $(2)$ then we can conclude that there can only be a solution for $q$ given $q_a$ and $q_b$ if and only if $q_{a,1} = q_{b,1}$. This essentially comes down to that both $q_a$ and $q_b$ represent a rotation of the same angle, which would be identical to the requirement that the rotation matrices $R_1$ and $R_2$ have the same eigenvalues/are similar. Another way of writing a quaternion is the axis-angle representation $\cos\left(\theta\over2\right) + \sin\left(\theta\over2\right)(u_x\,i+u_y\,j+u_z\,k)$, where $\theta$ is the angle and $\begin{bmatrix}u_x & u_y & u_z\end{bmatrix}^\top$ the (unit-)axis of rotation. So therefore we can conclude from equation $(2)$ and $(3)$ that $R(q)$ has to map the rotation axis of $q_a$, $\vec{u}_a$, to the rotation axis of $q_b$, $\vec{u}_b$, so $\vec{u}_b = R(q)\,\vec{u}_a$. There are infinitely many rotations which would satisfy this mapping.

The rotations with the smallest angle can be found by using a rotation axis perpendicular to both given axes, which can be obtained using the cross product of the two axes

$$
q_{\min} = \sqrt{\frac{1 + \vec{u}_a \cdot \vec{u}_b}{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{1 - \vec{u}_a \cdot \vec{u}_b}{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
i & j & k
\end{bmatrix}
\frac{\vec{u}_a \times \vec{u}_b}{\|\vec{u}_a \times \vec{u}_b\|} \tag{4}
$$

where $\vec{u}_a$ and $\vec{u}_b$ are both assumed to be of unit length.

The rotations with the largest angle can be found by rotating 180° around the average of the two axis

$$
q_{\max} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
i & j & k
\end{bmatrix}
\frac{\vec{u}_a + \vec{u}_b}{\|\vec{u}_a + \vec{u}_b\|}. \tag{5}
$$

And if it is desired these could be converted to rotation matrices. For example the rotation matrix corresponding to equation $(5)$ can simplified down to the following expression

$$
R_{\max} = \frac{1}{s_1^2 + s_2^2 + s_3^2}
\begin{bmatrix}
s_1^2-s_2^2-s_3^2 & 2\,s_1\,s_2 & 2\,s_1\,s_3 \\
2\,s_2\,s_1 & s_2^2-s_1^2-s_3^2 & 2\,s_2\,s_3 \\
2\,s_3\,s_1 & 2\,s_3\,s_2 & s_3^2-s_1^2-s_2^2
\end{bmatrix} \tag{6}
$$

with $s_n = q_{a,n+1} + q_{b,n+1}\ \forall\,n\in\{1,2,3\}$.

Answer (score 1):

After long hours of search, I realized that it is not a simple problem at all. There are many related papers exists published back in the 1980s [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03498.pdf), [2](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=326576). The short summary is as follows

\begin{equation}
^L\textbf{R} \textbf{R}=\textbf{R} ^C\textbf{R}
\end{equation}

$^L\textbf{R}_{i}=\boldsymbol{e}^{[^L\textbf{r}_i]_\times}
, ^C\textbf{R}_i=\boldsymbol{e}^{[^C\textbf{r}_i]_\times}$

$\textbf{M} = \sum_{i=1}^{I}{^L\textbf{r}_i {^C\textbf{r}_i^\top}}$

$\textbf{R} = (\textbf{M}^\top\textbf{M})^{-1/2}\textbf{M}^\top$

Single pair of rotation is not enough to decide the unique solution.

Also, the following post is actually asking the same question. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206623/solution-to-ax-xb-for-3-times3-rotation-matrices)

If scale translation should be considered as well, Eq 8.27 of [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-662-04567-1) has the answer.

Here is matlab implementation of this problem.[here](https://github.com/RobotMa/axxb_calibration)

Comment: This seems to be a continuation of your question, rather than a proper answer. If that's the case, you can append the contents of this answer in the question itself as an "edit", then remove the answer.

Comment: You are right I have edited it. As above contains the answer to the question as well, I just moved the question part to top.

Comment: Links might break, so could you give a summary of your solution in your answer.